# What is the right way to implement java webstart on a server?

Tags: java, server, java-web-start

I want to start my application with webstart, the program needs 3 external jars to work. I tried compiling with NetBeans uploading everything on the "dist" folder to the server and then accesing the server and trying to run the HTML. This didnt worked because there was an error about the paths of the external jars even if I indicated the right paths in the jnlp.

Error:

```
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: 
    Unable to load resource: http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib\commons-io-2.4.jar
```

So, the external jars go in the client computer and then I retrieve them from there?

JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Contenedores.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Contenedores</title>
    <vendor>Diego</vendor>
    <description>null</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Contenedores.jar" size="12407" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" size="185140" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/guava-18.0.jar" size="2256213" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar" size="23737" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Contenedores" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="contenedores.Contenedores"  name="Contenedores" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: You should really show the error message, as well as the paths, command lines, configuration files etc. If you feel you need to anonymize them, then just carefully (for example preserve whitespace, upper/lower case and other itsy bitsy details which often break things) rename the important part of the paths such as the project name (for example search-replace in text editor before pasting to the question).

Comment: @hyde sorry you are right I forgot to post the error. I added it now.

Comment: Not familiar with the subject so possibly not relevant but: 1. can you access the url with a browser or `wget` or something? 2. that ` \ ` looks mighty suspicious when it is part of the URL... in general you shouldn't have backslashes in paths in Java code, just normal `/` forward slashes.

Comment: Yeah that "\" is the problem. In the jnlp the path is lib/commons-io-2.4.jar but for some reason it changes the slash to "\" and I really dont know why

Comment: Can you show the jnlp you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually copy all the content in the generated HTML and JNLP into new files, upload those file to the server and remove the old ones and from some reason it worked.
A bug maybe? I dont know.